# How to change order of files listed by dir cmd

Tags: powershell

Currently upon using the dir command `dir /b *.*dot` my files are listed in the following random order.

```
C.dot
D.dot
B.dot
A.dot
```

What should be done so that the same command `dir /b *.*dot` returns an ordered list, i.e.

```
A.dot
B.dot
C.dot
D.dot
```

I was initially thinking about a `touch` like command and I have tried `copy /b A.dot+` trying to update timestamp but it did not work.

Please suggest which command can be used in windows / powershell to achieve this.

Comment: If you want a sorted list: sort the list. Problem solved. Don't *ever* rely on a directory listing returning the entries in any particular order.

Comment: `dir /b` is a cmd.exe internal command, not powershell. Append `/ON` to sort alpabetically

Comment: I need the listing returned by the dir command to automatically order it in a specific way because a software we use picks up that order.

Comment: What are the files currently being sorted by? Which property?

Comment: Then you need to fix your software. Please read ["What order does the DIR command arrange files if no sort order is specified?"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140304-00/?p=1603/). Money quote: *"Therefore, you shouldn't write a program that relies on any particular order of enumeration. (Or even that the order of enumeration is consistent between two runs!)"*

Comment: BTW, also from that article: moving everything out of that directory, and then back into it in the desired order will *probably* give you the desired result, but I doubt you'll find anyone who'll guarantee you that.

Comment: So far I have not found any means to reorder the listing. The program in question is Solidworks which may not consider flags for this specific operation. I believe it will be an enhancement request to get this feature added. I feel that editing the files in place and retaining them in the pre-existing folder will retain the ordering. will need to find out.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to sort by alphabetical order of the file name, use `Sort-Object`. So something like `Get-ChildItem -Path . -Filter "*.*dot" | Sort-Object -Property Name`. Or, if you insist on not using `Get-ChildItem`, you could do `dir /b *.*dot | Sort-Object`.

Comment: Thank you for the response but I do not need to sort the files, but reorder them in a specific way.

Comment: Reordering is sorting them by a property. It's still sorting.

Comment: I agree with Benjamin - sorting them could still do what you want, you just haven't provided enough info about your task at hand

Answer (score 0):

you mentioned touch, if you need the timestamp updated you can set the LastWriteTime

```
(Get-ChildItem a.dot).LastWriteTime = get-date
```

there might be a better way to do what you are trying to do lastwritetime is limited to minutes so you can only update one file per minute

i am just unsure how you would GCI into a random order...? dir (the same thing as get-ChildItem) is going to order by name unless you sort by something else.